# How do delegates improve the performance of an application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates

I am new to the delegates concept. I've learnt it is similar to pointers in C++. In its advantages, it mentioned effective use of delegates improves the performance.

Considering it's a pointer. How does it improve the performance of an application?

If anybody could explain this with a simple example, that would be helpful.

Comment: Where have you read that "it improves the performance of the application?"

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11657/Understanding-Delegates-in-C

Comment: Don't believe everything you read. Delegates are not intended to improve performance. They're intended to provide a really clean, beautiful callback pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegates aren't **directly** about improving performance - they are about abstracting invocation. In C++ terms, it is indeed like a method pointer.

Most uses of delegates are **not related to performance**. Let's be clear about that from the outset.

However, one main time this can be used to help with performance is that this allows for scenarios like meta-programming. The code (usually library code) can construct complex chains of behaviours based on configuration information *at runtime*, and then compile that information into a method via any of `Expression`, `TypeBuilder` or `DynamicMethod` (or basically any API that lets you construct IL). But to *invoke* such a dynamically generated method, you need a delegate - because your static IL that was compiled from C# can't refer to a method that *didn't exist* at the time.

Note that an alternative way to do this would be to use `TypeBuilder` to create (at runtime) a new type that inherits from a subclass or implements a known interface, then create an instance of the dynamically generated type, which can be cast to the expected API in the usual manner and invoked normally.

Answer (score 2):

Delegates do not have an significant positive or negative impact on the performance of your application. What they provide is a means of decoupling aspects of your application from each other.

Lets say you have a situation where class `A` calls `B.foo()`. `A` is now partially coupled to `B`. You might then have a situation where `B` needs to call `A.bar()`. You now risk tightly coupling the two together. If instead of exposing `A` to `B`, you instead provide `bar` as a delegate, then you have removed that coupling.